# Reporting Results: Active or Passive voice?

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

I am writing my first publication and I heard a lot of different opinions on the matter of using passive or active voice in publications.

This question focuses in particular on the results.

Should I say:

"The results show an increase in water pressure."

or

"An increase in water pressure is shown by the results."

The first seems more natural and concise to me. Yet the second puts the important statement (i.e. the result) first.

By the way, english isn't my first language, so I hope this question isn't trivial.

Cheers.